# Angular 2+ & Firebase REST API Send password reset email error problem

Tags: angular, firebase, http

I am learning Angular 2+ through Maximilian’s course on udemy. My level is junior.

I am using Firebase API for user authentication in a project and I added the “forgot password” feature.

The problem is that, for a signed up user it works and I receive an email back to reset the password but If I enter an email that doesn’t exist in the users list in Firebase (non signeup email) It doesn't trigger the error message, it just accepts it but it doesn’t send an email to this address (checked with a non signed up email). Firebase includes a common error codes section though. I can’t even log any error to check the error object.

I am following the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-send-password-reset-email as I did for login and signup (these work like a charm)

Any help will be very much appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

The service code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, catchError, tap, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export interface ResetData {
  email:string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PassResetService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient,
  ) { }

  private apiKey:string = 'my-api-key';
  private resetEndpoint:string = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=';
  private resetUrl:string = this.resetEndpoint + this.apiKey;

  reset( email:string ) {
    const payload = { requestType:'PASSWORD_RESET',  email: email };
    return this.http
      .post<ResetData>( this.resetUrl, payload )
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
      )
  }

  private handleError( errorResponse:HttpErrorResponse ):Observable<never> {

    console.log(errorResponse);

    let errorMessage = 'An unknown error occured!';
    
    if (!errorResponse.error || !errorResponse.error.error)
      return throwError(() => errorMessage);

    const message = errorResponse.error.error.message;

    if (message === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')
      errorMessage = 'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.';

    return throwError(() => errorMessage);

  }

}
```

The component class code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PassResetService } from './pass-reset.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-password-reset',
  templateUrl: './password-reset.component.html',
  styles: [`

    .loginBox {
      margin-top:100px;
      box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
  
  `]
})
export class PasswordResetComponent {

  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private passReset:PassResetService
  ) { }

  isLoading?:boolean;
  errorMessage:string | null = null;
  successAlert:boolean = false;

  onSubmit( form:NgForm ):void {

    if (!form.valid) return;

    this.isLoading = true;

    const email = form.value.email;

    this.passReset.reset(email).subscribe({
      next: responseData => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.successAlert = true;
        console.log(responseData);
        setTimeout(() => this.successAlert = false, 3000);
      },
      error: responseError => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log(responseError);
        this.errorMessage = responseError;
      }
    });

    form.reset();
  }

  onCancelClick():void {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  onCloseAlert():void {
    this.errorMessage = null;
  }

}
```

The component Template: (code is probably a mess, I'm sorry for that!)

```
<div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-11 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 loginBox p-5 pb-4">
        <img class="pnetlogo mb-4" src="logo source" alt="logo">
        <div>
            <h3 class="mb-3">Find Your Account</h3>
            <p *ngIf="!isLoading && !successAlert">Please enter your email address to reset your password.</p>

            <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger p-2 ps-3 pe-3 rounded-1" role="alert">
                    {{ errorMessage }}
                <div class="mt-2"><a (click)="onCloseAlert()" class="text-danger cursor-pointer">close</a></div>
            </div>
            
            <div *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
            <form *ngIf="!isLoading && !successAlert" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : !email.valid && email.touched}"
                        class="shadow-none form-control fw-light rounded-1" 
                        type="text" placeholder="Email"
                        name="email" #email="ngModel" required email ngModel>
                    <div *ngIf="(!email.valid && email.touched)" class="form-text text-danger">Email is required.</div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="pbtn btn-primary me-2" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
                <button (click)="onCancelClick()" type="button" class="pbtn btn-secondary me-2">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            <div *ngIf="successAlert">
                <div class="alert alert-success rounded-1" role="alert">
                    A password reset request has been sent, check your email!
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <span class="form-text">Go <a routerLink="/login" class="cursor-pointer pnetorangelight nodecor">back</a>.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `sendOobCode` [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendOobCode):

> Sends an out-of-band confirmation code for an account.

From that it seems correct that this API only works for existing Firebase Authentication/Google Cloud Identity accounts.

For new accounts, you'll want to use the [`signInWithEmailLink` API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithEmailLink).

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for replying! It's true, it seems that it only works for existing accounts but it's a little weird that they provide an error code: EMAIL_NOT_FOUND. I believe this has to trigger whenever you enter a non signed up email, yeah? I just can't figure out how to trigger it when entering a non existing account!!